# Content Staging - missing document references

Tags: kentico

I'm working with Kentico EMS 12's content staging feature. I have a number of pages I've attempted to sync to a new environment. It seems everything goes well except in circumstances where I have a page type that has a reference to another document (e.g. I might have a page with a web part containing a reference to a particular form that shows in a modal popup). It seems those references are blank in the destination environment, and I'm forced to re-select them across the board. Is there any particular approach to using the staging feature that would prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO Mike!

FYI, no need to cross post questions on SO AND the DevNet.  As long as you tag your SO posts with `kentico` they will automatically be brought into DevNet.

You need to have the objects (page types, transformations, templates, widgets, page templates, etc.) in the new environment first before you can successfully sync pages over.  Pages have far too many dependencies on objects.  The sync mechanism does not automatically sync those objects over based on a page so many reasons.  So make sure any objects associated/related with that page are actually created/synced to the new environment FIRST.  Once they exist in that new environment, then you should be set.  If you make updates to those objects, no worries simply because the IDs already exist and that's what the page is looking for.